# Dynamically added content not taking alert function

Tags: jquery, dynamic

Dynamically added content not taking alert function. I tried many ways to make this work but i am not able to get it right. I am sharing the fiddle.

Note: Please fork new fiddle when you are editing it.

thanks in advance.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/kc5aa/2/`
```

Comment: Add your fiddle please.

Comment: on which event you are trying to show `alert()`? have you tried `.on()`?

Comment: Yes i have tried all that. please check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc5aa/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to bind event using `.on()` for dynamically generated elements. This will work for normal elements also.

change on click event binding of checkbox to below code :

```
 $('.container').on("click",'.checkBox',function () {
        if ($('.checkBox').is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).val())
        }
    });
```

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kc5aa/4/)**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click) for using `.on()` for dynamic elements.

Comment: Do you have any special reason to delegate the click from the .container instead of, for instance, the document itself ?

Comment: yes, if I use `document` then it will bind all checkboxes with class="checkBox" inside html and that may get wrong. OP want to target only checkboxes inside `container` div.

Comment: Okay sure, didn't think about it, but is there also any difference at memory level or execution speed for instance ?

Comment: yes, it creates single handler.. more information is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 0):

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/LufQa/)

```
  $(document).on('click','.checkBox', function () {
    if ($('.checkBox').is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val())
    }
});
```